# Unitils @DataSet annotation

Tags: annotations, unitils

I have a theoretical question this time. Where is unitils @Dataset annotation processed? Every annotation must have a prosessor class, see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/java-annotations-explored-explained.html

Does this happen in org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4 library?

I would like to make my own implementation for anotation, no code ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which part of the processing that you are looking for.  If you mean where the actual DataSet is processed, then check out the *DbUnitModule* class.  From the [API](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/dbunit/DbUnitModule.html):

> Loading of DbUnit data sets can be done by annotating a class or method with the DataSet
>   annotation. The name of the data set files can be specified explicitly as an argument of
>   the annotation. If no file name is specified, it looks for a file in the same directory
>   as the test class named: 'classname without packagename'.xml.

If you are referring to the code that actually looks for things that are annotated with *@DataSet* then they have a helper class called *AnnotationUtils* ([API](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/util/AnnotationUtils.html)) which has a bunch of methods for accessing annotated items.  This is used by the *DbUnitModule* mentioned above to find whatever data set is needed for a given test.